# How to generate custom identification values in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good day guys, I have two(2) fields, `persondId` (primary key) which is auto incremented and `personCode` which should be a custom four(4) digits incremented value based on the `personId` field.

For example when when a record is inserted into the **persons** table `personId` becomes `1` and `personCode` should become `0001`

How do I accomplish this in laravel?

Migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('person-code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

    $person = new Person;
    $person->name = request('name');

    $person->save();
}
```

Model

```
//Please how should my model look to accomplish this.
```

Comment: For this you can create another table to store the incremented value and on insert of persons table you can update the personcode field and increment the value from the table

Comment: do you need personCode cant you just `str_pad($persondId, 4 ,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` or `sprintf('%04d', $persondId)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    /*
        setup vars...
    */

    public function getPersonCodeAttribute()
    {
        return str_pad($this->getKey(), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}
```

In your controller foo method

```
public function foo()
{
    $model = MyModel::find(5);
    echo $model->person_code;   // 0005
    echo $model->personCode;    // 0005
    echo $model->Person_code;   // 0005
    echo $model->PersonCode;    // 0005
}
```

Alternative version when you actually have the person_code column

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    /*
        setup vars...
    */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($model) {
            $model->person_code = str_pad($model->getKey(), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        });
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that Laravel's event listeners are triggered only with certain conditions, like to trigger the `creating` event you need to execute `MyModel::create()` or `MyModel->save()` method on new, non existing data

EDIT: Here is solution for your case. Few tips:
Your table name should be equivalent to model's name, so for table People you should have a model named People. Eloquent have it's own naming conventions, but following them is not necessary and if you want to read about them, visit this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Your migration should be:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');           // UNSIGNED BIG INTEGER 
        $table->string('person_code', 20);  // (18446744073709551615 => 20 chars)
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And model:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'people';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';       // as long as the primary column name is "id", this line is not required actually

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'person_code'
    ];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($model) {
            $model->person_code = str_pad($model->getKey(), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I persist this to the database? How should my migration file looks like?

Comment: I think you dont understand the code here. The code from getPersonCodeAttribute method is executed whenever you type `$model->person_code` or `$model->personCode` etc. You don't even need the person_code column in your database.

Comment: This gets the value of primary key column (`$this->getKey()`) and pads it with zeroes to the total length of 4

Comment: Your're right, I really don't understand. So, what you're saying is that instead of having the **personCode** column I can just have the **personId** column do that?

Comment: Check second solution if you want to stay with person_code column. Ah, and zero-padding data has to be varchar. What I did in first solution is actually the same what getter is for C#

Comment: I want to go with the second solution, but pardon me that things are still blurring to me. I have updated my post to show a bit of how I want to accomplish. Is there a way I can merge my code with yours?

Comment: You can't store '0005' value in integer column. I mentioned this before

Comment: I know it has been a very long time. I have gotten my head around it now seeing a bit of light. But continues to generate `0000` for every record I insert.